# "Forgot" password on login form interferes with browser filler

Tags: bug, design, login

Safari 9 on OS X introduced a key indicator to allow you to select a password from the Keychain. However, the "Forgot" link inside of the text box makes it unusable. Attempting to click the key always results in the forgot link getting clicked.

[image]

It is occasionally useful to be able to use the key to select a password.

Comment: Or is this a Safari bug? Doesn't adding that stuff to the UI technically make it non-compliant with the HTML spec?

Comment: @Anko other browsers do that. [IE10 does something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842665/internet-explorer-10-windows-8-remove-text-input-and-password-action-icons) for clearing fields and unmasking the password.

Comment: Oh yeah, I need to move that link anyway. I keep forgetting to.

Comment: @vcsjones Do you mean to imply that because it's popular it must be good, or that Internet Explorer just has the same bug? :)

Answer (score -1):

Look at the upper field, i.e. email. Once you click it, you get the keychain popup allowing you to select the email/password pair.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to work around the issue, however it's still something that should probably be fixed. It doesn't look clean and it breaks the users expectations with the browser.

Comment: @vcs "It is occasionally useful to be able to use the key to select a password" - your question is answered. Doesn't it appear an issue related to Safari? It doesn't bother me to much...